# How to explain the 'weird' results about __getattribute__, __getattr__?

Tags: python

```
class B(object):
"""new style class"""

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        print '__getattribute__ called'
        return super(B, self).__getattribute__(name)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        print '__getattr__ called'

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        print '__setattr__ called'
        if name in ['forbid', 'refuse']:
            raise AttributeError('Attribute name invalid!')
        else:
            return super(B, self).__setattr__(name, value)
```

B class is defined as the above,next I try to do some tests about `__getattr__,__getattribute__`:

```
b = B()
setattr(b, 'test', 100)

print b.__dict__
print b.__getattribute__('__dict__')
print b.__getattr__('__dict__')
print getattr(b, '__dict__')
```

Finally the results is that:

```
__getattribute__ called
{'test': 100}
__getattribute__ called
__getattribute__ called
{'test': 100}
__getattribute__ called
__getattr__ called
None
__getattribute__ called
{'test': 100}
```

Here come my questions:

1.`print b.__getattribute__('__dict__')` called `__getattribute__` twice,why?

2.`print b.__getattr__('__dict__')`called `__getattribute__`first and then called `__getattr__`next? why return None?

The results above seem so weird to me.I really don't understand how these methods worked.Any advice or suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: For Q2, `__getattr__` is responsible for the `return None`; all it does is `print`.

Comment: For Q1, `__getattribute__` is called to resolve `__getattribute__`!

Comment: @jonrsharpe Q2,before `__getattr__` is called,`__getattribute__` has been called,where is the `return` of `__getattribute__`?I need to know how these methods work in order explicitly if you could tell,thanks:)

Comment: The `return` from `__getattribute__` *is `__getattr__`*, which is called returning nothing; `b.__getattr__()` is really `b.__getattribute__("__getattr__")()`, and `b.__getattribute__()` is `b.__getattribute__("__getattribute__")()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The first `__getattribute__` call is done when you do `b.__getattribute__`. You want to get the attribute called `__getattribute__` (yeah, I know that sounds pretty rad). When you request the attribute called `__getattribute__`, then `__getattribute__` is called and you get the `__getattribute__` method in result. Then you just call the `__getattribute__` method - here's the second call of `__getattribute__`
2. `b.__getattr__` calls `__getattribute__` to get attribute called `__getattr__` (yeah, I know). You get the `__getattr__` method in return. Then you call the `__getattr__` method. It doesn't return anything explicitly which means it returns None implicitly.

Here's the simplified version of what happens when you see `some_obj_of_class_B.some_method()`:

- `__getattribute__` is called to get the attribute called `some_method`. `__getattribute__` prints 'I was called!' and delegates its job to `object.__getattribute__` (which, I think, examines some_obj_of_class_B's `__dict__`, examines its class `__dict__`, base classes `__dict__`, handles descriptors, etc. Hopefully `object.__getattribute__` returns `some_method` (which is hopefully a function or more precisely a bound method)
- This function/bound method is called. In your case a bound method is `__getattribute__` itself. That's why it called twice.

Comment: Nice explanation!I got it:) @Nigel Tufnel

Comment: Effectively, per my comment above, e.g. `b.__getattribute__()` is `b.__getattribute__("__getattribute__")()`